# How can I enable auto-completion for the snap command?

Tags: command-line, snap

I am used to auto-completion for the command `sudo apt-get install nam`. Pressing tab will autocomplete the command to `sudo apt-get install name`.

The same method, however, does not work by default for `sudo snap install nam`.

How can I enable auto-completion for the `snap` command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`snap` used to have some autocompletion, but I believe it's being revamped right now. Here are the bugs in question:

- [autocompletion of commands](https://bugs.launchpad.net/snappy/+bug/1566604)
- [autocompletion of local files](https://bugs.launchpad.net/snappy/+bug/1600083)
- [autocompletion for remote snaps](https://bugs.launchpad.net/snappy/+bug/1400802)

Comment: That bug was for autocompletion of commands. Like snap ins<tab>, which is working now.
This one is for completion in install for the local files: https://bugs.launchpad.net/snappy/+bug/1600083

This one is for completion in install for remote snaps:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/snappy/+bug/1400802