# Enable snap TAB-completion for zsh

Tags: snap, zsh, auto-completion

Does anybody have an idea how to get the TAB-completion for zsh working for the `snap` command?
According to the answer in [How can I enable auto-completion for the snap command?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/795253/how-can-i-enable-auto-completion-for-the-snap-command) it should be working right now but it does not complete at all for me for the `snap` command