# How do I enable zsh package suggestions as in Ubuntu bash?

Tags: command-line, zsh, auto-completion

I'm slowly transitioning to zsh from bash and am loving almost every part of it, but there are two things I'm really missing. One of them is snap completions, see here:
[Enable snap TAB-completion for zsh](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1151130/enable-snap-tab-completion-for-zsh)

The other is that sort of thing where you type a command into the Ubuntu terminal and instead of going 'oh no! command not found!' right away, you get something like this:

```
user@computer:~$ inkscape

Command 'inkscape' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo snap install inkscape  # version 0.92.4, or
sudo apt  install inkscape  # version 0.92.4-5ubuntu5

See 'snap info inkscape' for additional versions.
```

Is there some way to enable this in zsh? I really would like to stop having to switch back to bash just to use this and snap autocompletion.

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For **apt package suggestions** we may do it with following:

```
$ sudo apt install command-not-found
$ echo "source /etc/zsh_command_not_found" >> ~/.zshrc
$ exec zsh
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this. I have wanted to do this for a while. BTW...At the top of this answer it says "for apt package suggestions" although it also includes snaps. `command-not-found` is installed by default, and it is used in the default Ubuntu bash.

Answer (score 7):

if you are using **oh-my-zsh**, it comes with plugin called `command-not-found`, you can enable it by editing ~/.zshrc, add `command-not-found` in plugins list.

e.g.
plugins=(command-not-found)

Comment: This is the the easiest solution out there!

Comment: Thanks a lot! I already use oh-my-zsh, and this is the best solution for me :)

Answer (score 2):

The magic happens under the hood in `bash` using a function called `command_not_found_handle`:

```
$ declare -f command_not_found_handle
command_not_found_handle () 
{ 
    if [ -x /usr/lib/command-not-found ]; then
        /usr/lib/command-not-found -- "$1";
        return $?;
    else
        if [ -x /usr/share/command-not-found/command-not-found ]; then
            /usr/share/command-not-found/command-not-found -- "$1";
            return $?;
        else
            printf "%s: command not found\n" "$1" 1>&2;
            return 127;
        fi;
    fi
}
```

`zsh` has a very similarly named `command_not_found_handler`:

- [Intercept “command not found” error in zsh](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5373/intercept-command-not-found-error-in-zsh)

which (at least in my 18.04 installation) appears to be unset by default. Although there may be better solutions, I don't see any reason why you shouldn't simply copy the `bash` function to `zsh` (with an appropriate change of name of course):

```
command_not_found_handler () {
    if [ -x /usr/lib/command-not-found ]
    then
        /usr/lib/command-not-found -- "$1"
        return $?
    else
        if [ -x /usr/share/command-not-found/command-not-found ]
        then
            /usr/share/command-not-found/command-not-found -- "$1"
            return $?
        else
            printf "%s: command not found\n" "$1" >&2
            return 127
        fi
    fi
}
```

You can place the definition in your `~/.zshrc` or other appropriate initialization file.

Comment: This worked for me! Thank you so much!