# How to get `Command <insert command> is available in the following places` in zsh

Tags: zsh

[SOLVED]

I just wanted to ask if anyone knows a plugin or any way to get this functionality in ZSH (picture is on bash):

[image: image here]

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, zsh 5.8 with zinit as my plugin manager

Thanks for the help, answer's here [How to get `Command <insert command> is available in the following places` in zsh](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1385347/how-to-get-command-insert-command-is-available-in-the-following-places-in-zs#comment2390818_1385347)

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to include: (0) the version of Ubuntu you’re running (1) where you saw the function you’d like to replicate. This may make it more likely that someone can answer the question 

Comment: This is part of the `command-not-found` functionality - as such, the solution should be the same as [How do I enable zsh package suggestions as in Ubuntu bash?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1226574/how-do-i-enable-zsh-package-suggestions-as-in-ubuntu-bash)